# Having edges be a different shader than the mesh

Tags: rendering, shaders

Is it possible to create letters, for example, the letters have one shader, but the edge of the letters have a different shader?

Comment: You can add as many shaders as you have faces on a mesh.  Please edit your question to be more specific about what you're looking for.

Comment: I want the face of  the letters to be one color, but the edges of the letters i want to be a different color.

Comment: Please add some images for the reference of desired effect. Generally you can't apply material to only edges. You might add Wireframe modifier to the object which will add geometry on the edges or use Freestyle to render outlines on the edges of the object

Comment: How do i add images?

Comment: Click the edit link on your quesiton: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1083/38953

Comment: It wont let me add an image. It says it is uploading but it wont for some reason.

Comment: To try to explain it better, what I want to do, is create a cube that is (blue) but the edges I want to be (red). Is this possible?

Comment: You can't have"shaders" anywhere. You can apply **materials** to faces only, edges have no actual geometry so can't be rendered nor have materials by themselves. Only exception being wireframe materials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender supports [text objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/texts/introduction.html). While you can [extrude](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/texts/properties.html#geometry) the text it doesn't provide a way to alter the material used on the sides. A [solidify modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html) can extrude the text shape and also allow assigning a different material to the side (and back if desired).

- Add a text object. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*->Text*. Edit the object to alter the text, select the desired font.

[image: add text object]

- Create multiple [materials](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/assigning_a_material.html#creating-a-new-material).

[image: multiple materials]

- Add a solidify modifier, set the thickness to suit.

[image: add a solidify modifier]

- Set the material index for the rim and back if desired. The material index is zero based which means 0 is the first material in the list and 1 is the second...

[image: solidify settigns]

[image: result]